# Is damage from the spell Wall of Fire rolled once or rerolled each time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, damage, artificer

I am playing an Artillerist Artificer, using an Arcane Firearm (5th level feature) which states:

> When you cast an artificer spell through the firearm, roll a d8, and you gain a bonus to one of the spell’s damage rolls equal to the number rolled.

*Wall of fire* (4th level Artillerist spell) states:

> One side of the wall, selected by you when you cast this spell, deals 5d8 fire damage to each creature that ends its turn within 10 feet of that side or inside the wall. A creature takes the same damage when it enters the wall for the first time on a turn or ends its turn there.

As it's saying that the creature takes the same damage does that mean you use your first 5d8 roll throughout the duration of the spell (thus having the arcane firearms extra d8 active for the whole duration?) or do you roll each time (thus only getting the first damage boost?)

Comment: You seem to have already figured out that *if* you don't reroll the damage, the boost applies to every instance of damage. So your question comes down to  "is damage of *wall of fire* rerolled each time?", and we've already got a question about exactly the same problem with a different spell, so I've closed this as a duplicate. While it is a about a different spell, it seems to be the same problem, which is ambiguous language about "this damage"/"same damage". Let us know if it does not answer your question.

Comment: Cheers @ThomasMarkov this does answer the question, i'd already searched through all the artificer related content and must have missed that question!

Comment: No worries, it took me a couple of tries to find it. This is where having duplicates is helpful - it will make it easier to find the question next time someone searches for it, because yours could show up in searches the target does not.

Comment: Business aside, welcome to the stack! Take the [tour] when you have a moment, and have a look around the [help] for more information about the site.